# Firebase Realtime Database on Android - Persistence

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I need a clarification about enabling **persistence** in Android for Firebase Realtime Database. Docs says:

> "With disk persistence enabled, our synced data and writes will be
>   persisted to disk across app restarts and our app should work
>   seamlessly in offline situations."

so my question is: after an app restarts, how can I retrieve data from persistence without making another query?
For example if I save the last record key, I can do the query as

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt(LAST_KEY)
```

but the problem is that i cannot retrieve previously saved data.
**Should I use a local database to store data?**
Thanks

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking. If you restart the app without a network connection, the same listeners as before will work, but will get their results from the disk-based cache.

Comment: Hi Frank,thanks for your reply. This is the scenario: I have a list to keep update and to do that I use a childEventListener; but if the user restarts the phone or the app, the listener downloads the entire list again (and in firebase console I see high peak of usage); I want to know  if there is a way to retrieve data from the persistence of the local firebase database instance.

Comment: The listener does not necessarily re-download all data. But it definitely will need to do a sync. There is no separate API that only loads from the local cache. But if you call `goOffline()`, you can prevent Firebase from synchronizing. You should wonder though why you're using a cloud-hosted, realtime synchronizing database in that case. It seems easier to use a simpler database (such as Google Cloud Datastore) and store the data in a local database.

Comment: Hi Frank,thanks again for your reply.
I just checked the code and the childListener works correctly, it loads first the persistence data and after the data from sync; but there’s something I don’t understand.
The database reference has persistence enabled and ‘keepSync(true)’: everytime I call the database reference (only in onCreate), I first check if there is an existing listener and if so I detach it; my database size is 780KB but in firebase console I see peaks of 2MB everytime i restart the app, and I am the only user. I check everything but I don’t understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

.keepSynced(true); 
it will sync your latest data up to 10 MB into the local data storage, even you restart the app data is already present in firebase local storage.